# Trustworthy url address for bitcoin download?

Tags: wallet, trust

I would like to download install some bitcoin software and create a wallet. I know there are some programs like Bitcoin-QT or Multibit. There are more sources to download these programs. I want to be sure, I downloaded the right one.

Which software from which url is trustworthy? Can I check the checksum of the downloaded installer of specific version against some MD5 from a list somewhere, that it is safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bitcoin.org/en/download is the official download page for bitcoin-qt, it is the oldest client, the most trustworthy and it is the client I would recommend for a beginner.

The same client can also be downloaded from the Bitcoin Core website, here: https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/

Comment: I have visited the site before, but I was not sure if it is trustworthy, because, I do not see any security. I would expect https protocol or any web signature (green signature on the left url bar). If I am paranoic I cannot be sure that my provider's DNS server redirect me to the right place.

Comment: It's https now.